# Where is the Temp folder in OS X?

Tags: macos, temporary-files

I am working on a project that stores output files in the Temp folder. In Windows I can search the Temp folder but I don't know the location of Temp folder in OS X.

Can you please guide me to the location of said folder?

Comment: Related: [How to determine public temp directory on OS X to be write-accessible by www server?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/210942/22781) at AD

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use: `echo $TMPDIR`.

To open and browse the folder, use `open $TMPDIR`.

Sources:

- [How do I find out the system temporary directory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/how-do-i-find-out-the-system-temporary-directory)
- [OSX: API for retrieving path to user's ~/temp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293348/osx-api-for-retrieving-path-to-users-temp-folder)

Answer (score 45):

`/tmp` is also a temporary directory.  Files are deleted from `/tmp` upon reboot.
To access it from Finder, use <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> in Mavericks) and enter `/tmp` in the dialogue box.  From a terminal, just `cd /tmp`.